# how to check if an element is enabled

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I need to check with Protractor if a button in my angular application is enabled, for so this is my test:

```
    it('submit should not be enabled',function() {
      var price = by.name('price'),
          oldCategory = by.name('oldCategory'),
          newCategory = by.name('newCategory'),
          oldPayment = by.name('oldPayment'),
          newPayment = by.name('newPayment'),
          item = by.name('item'),
          submit = by.id('submitButton');
      expect(submit.isEnabled().toBe(false)); 
  });
```

when I run the test, get this error:

```
 TypeError: Object By.name("price") has no method 'isEnabled'
```

Comment: Not sure why `isEnabled` is being called on `By.name("price")`.

Comment: thanks, how should I do?

Comment: What I mean is I don't see a place in the sample code where the method `isEnabled` is called on the object `By.name("price")` as the error seems to indicate.

Comment: sorry the error is:  TypeError: Object By.id("submitButton") has no method 'isEnabled'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The parenthesis is misplaced in the [`expectation`](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) :

```
expect(submit.isEnabled().toBe(false));
```

it should be :

```
expect(submit.isEnabled()).toBe(false);
```

---

And you misuse the [`protractor locator`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#locator-strategies) :

```
submit = by.id('submitButton');
```

it should be :

```
submit = element(by.id('submitButton'));
```

---

You could find a lot of examples in the [specs of protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/basic/findelements_spec.js).

Comment: it does not work: TypeError: Object By.id("submitButton") has no method 'isEnabled'

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
submit = element(by.id('submitButton'));
```

Comment: now I get this error:  TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'toBe'

Comment: You had: `expect(submit.isEnabled().toBe(false));`, which I think is missing a closing paren after `isEnabled()`.  It really should be: `expect(submit.isEnabled()).toBe(false));`

Comment: No. It should be `expect(submit.isEnabled()).toBe(false);`